# How to re order datas in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

I'm trying to re order my datas, I already found the code to use but it doesn't seem to work... 
Can you help me please ?

This is my code :

```
#code for my boxplot

     dat.m2 <- melt(H1,id.vars='fusion', measure.vars=c('FF','FM')) 
    dat.m2 <- melt(H1,id.vars='fusion', measure.vars=c('FF','FM')) 
    ggplot(dat.m2)+   geom_boxplot(aes(x=fusion, y=value, colour=variable))+   facet_wrap(~H1$Genotype)+ 
      xlab(" ")+   ylab("Days after sowing")

#code tried to re order
levels(dat.m2$fusion)
dat.m2$fusion<-factor(dat.m2$fusion, levels=c("Control", "CK20", "CK100", "CK500", "GA20", "GA100", "GA500"))
```

I tried to run again the first code after re ordering but it didn't work...

You can also find attached the image of the boxplot that I'm trying to modify

Thanks

EDIT :

```
> dput(head(H1, 20))
structure(list(Genotype = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("F1045", 
"FF", "M1585", "M1610"), class = "factor"), X = structure(c(1L, 
105L, 116L, 127L, 138L, 149L, 160L, 171L, 182L, 2L, 13L, 24L, 
35L, 46L, 57L, 68L, 79L, 90L, 101L, 106L), .Label = c("H1", "H10", 
"H100", "H101", "H102", "H103", "H104", "H105", "H106", "H107", 
"H108", "H109", "H11", "H110", "H111", "H112", "H113", "H114", 
"H115", "H116", "H117", "H118", "H119", "H12", "H120", "H121", 
"H122", "H123", "H124", "H125", "H126", "H127", "H128", "H129", 
"H13", "H130", "H131", "H132", "H133", "H134", "H135", "H136", 
"H137", "H138", "H139", "H14", "H140", "H141", "H142", "H143", 
"H144", "H145", "H146", "H147", "H148", "H149", "H15", "H150", 
"H151", "H152", "H153", "H154", "H155", "H156", "H157", "H158", 
"H159", "H16", "H160", "H161", "H162", "H163", "H164", "H165", 
"H166", "H167", "H168", "H169", "H17", "H170", "H171", "H172", 
"H173", "H174", "H175", "H176", "H177", "H178", "H179", "H18", 
"H180", "H181", "H182", "H183", "H184", "H185", "H186", "H187", 
"H188", "H189", "H19", "H190", "H191", "H192", "H2", "H20", "H21", 
"H22", "H23", "H24", "H25", "H26", "H27", "H28", "H29", "H3", 
"H30", "H31", "H32", "H33", "H34", "H35", "H36", "H37", "H38", 
"H39", "H4", "H40", "H41", "H42", "H43", "H44", "H45", "H46", 
"H47", "H48", "H49", "H5", "H50", "H51", "H52", "H53", "H54", 
"H55", "H56", "H57", "H58", "H59", "H6", "H60", "H61", "H62", 
"H63", "H64", "H65", "H66", "H67", "H68", "H69", "H7", "H70", 
"H71", "H72", "H73", "H74", "H75", "H76", "H77", "H78", "H79", 
"H8", "H80", "H81", "H82", "H83", "H84", "H85", "H86", "H87", 
"H88", "H89", "H9", "H90", "H91", "H92", "H93", "H94", "H95", 
"H96", "H97", "H98", "H99"), class = "factor"), Hormone = structure(c(2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("CK", "Control", "GA"), class = "factor"), 
    Hormone.quantity = structure(c(4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
    4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("100", 
    "20", "500", "Control"), class = "factor"), fusion = structure(c(4L, 
    4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
    4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("CK 100", "CK 20", "CK 500", 
    "Control", "GA 100", "GA 20", "GA 500"), class = "factor"), 
    DL = c(16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 
    16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L), LI = c(100L, 
    100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 
    100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L), Temperature = c(21L, 
    21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 
    21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L), Sowing.date = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "25-mrt", class = "factor"), BTD10 = structure(c(6L, 
    7L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    6L, 4L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("16-apr", "17-apr", "18-apr", 
    "19-apr", "21-mei", "23-apr", "26-apr", "30-apr"), class = "factor"), 
    FFLDT = structure(c(13L, 18L, 4L, 9L, 18L, 3L, 2L, 13L, 8L, 
    10L, 18L, 10L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 10L, 11L, 11L, 1L, 11L), .Label = c("", 
    "10-mei", "14-apr", "14-mei", "17-mei", "18-jun", "21-mei", 
    "23-apr", "24-mei", "26-apr", "28-mei", "3-apr", "3-mei", 
    "30-apr", "31-mei", "4-jun", "7-jun", "7-mei"), class = "factor"), 
    FH = structure(c(42L, 62L, 67L, 18L, 59L, 7L, 5L, 52L, 53L, 
    62L, 65L, 58L, 53L, 42L, 52L, 58L, 24L, 55L, 1L, 54L), .Label = c("", 
    "10", "10,5", "11", "11,5", "11,7", "12", "12,3", "12,5", 
    "13", "13,5", "14", "14,3", "14,5", "15", "15,3", "15,5", 
    "16", "16-jan", "17", "18", "18,5", "19", "20", "20,5", "21", 
    "21,5", "22", "22,5", "23", "23,5", "24,5", "25", "25,5", 
    "26", "26,5", "27", "27,5", "29", "29-mei", "3", "3,5", "30", 
    "30,5", "31,5", "32", "32,5", "33", "35", "36", "37", "4", 
    "4,5", "40", "42", "43", "47", "5", "5,5", "53", "55", "6", 
    "6,5", "7", "8", "8,5", "9", "9,5"), class = "factor"), SRDT = structure(c(3L, 
    8L, 1L, 1L, 8L, 1L, 8L, NA, NA, NA, 4L, NA, 15L, 12L, 14L, 
    14L, 15L, 15L, 1L, 15L), .Label = c("", "10-mei", "11-jun", 
    "13-jun", "13-mei", "14-mei", "17-mei", "18-jun", "21-jun", 
    "21-mei", "24-mei", "28-mei", "3-mei", "31-mei", "4-jun", 
    "7-jun", "7-mei"), class = "factor"), MH = c(26, 50, NA, 
    NA, 46, NA, 61, NA, NA, NA, 40, NA, 68, 48, 47, 42, 26, 50, 
    NA, 48), SEEDT = structure(c(2L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 
    NA, NA, NA, 4L, NA, 9L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 4L), .Label = c("", 
    "11-jun", "13-jun", "18-jun", "20-mei", "21-jun", "28-mei", 
    "31-mei", "4-jun", "6-apr", "7-jun"), class = "factor"), 
    FERMK = c(7L, 8L, NA, NA, 8L, NA, 8L, NA, NA, NA, 5L, NA, 
    7L, 6L, 7L, 6L, NA, NA, NA, 4L), PLRMK = c(1L, 2L, NA, NA, 
    1L, NA, 1L, NA, NA, NA, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, NA, 
    1L), BT = structure(c(5L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("", 
    "22", "23", "25", "29", "32", "bino"), class = "factor"), 
    FF = c(39L, 43L, 50L, 60L, 43L, 20L, 46L, 39L, 29L, 32L, 
    43L, 32L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 32L, 64L, 64L, NA, 64L), FM = c(78L, 
    85L, NA, NA, 85L, NA, 85L, NA, NA, NA, 80L, NA, 71L, 64L, 
    67L, 67L, 71L, 71L, NA, 71L), SEED = c(78L, 85L, NA, NA, 
    85L, NA, 85L, NA, NA, NA, 85L, NA, 71L, 67L, 67L, 67L, 85L, 
    80L, NA, 85L)), row.names = c(NA, 20L), class = "data.frame")
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, please consider providing a [reproducible dataset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: Hi, should I put all my datas ?

Comment: Have a look at `fct_reorder()` from the `forcats` package. It changes factor level order.

Comment: You could paste the output of `dput(df)` where `df` is your dataframe (if the dataframe is not too large); otherwise, you could use a publicly available dataset, e.g., `mpg`, and try to reproduce your problem there.

Comment: Please edit **the question** with the output of `dput(df)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(df, 20))`. (`df` is the name of your dataset.)

Comment: It's done, I added the output of dput(head(df, 20))

Comment: Don't use `facet_wrap(~H1$Genotype)` if the data you are using in `ggplot2` is `dat.m2`. Simply write `facet_wrap(~Genotype)`.